# Mount a detected but not listed in disks list SD card

Tags: mount, disk, fdisk, sd-card

My problem is a bit complicated to describe knowing that I'm not really a passionate about partitioning, but here's what I'm trying to do, What I tried and what doesn't work :

## Goal

My goal is to simply mount and reset my micro-sd card. It putted it in a micro-sd to sd adapater (female micro-sd/male sd) in order to access it from my laptop. It's not an OS problem, as I have similar problems on my other PC with this micro-sd card, and it's not the adapter, I have tried with a micro-sd to usb-A adapter.

## What I tried and doesn't work (and why)

### Linux (Fedora)

#### GUI-based programs

##### GNOME File Explorer

My SD card isn't listed.

##### GNOME disk software

In the disk selection, my micro-sd card appears. I can select it, and formatting operation are visibles. But when I try to format it, the following error is displayed : `udisk-error-quark, 0`. Performance tests returns an error too.

##### Gparted

When launching gparted, I can see that informations about my sd card are loaded (and are surprisingly long) in the footer, but it just doesn't appears in the disk list at all.

##### Raspberry Pi Imager

I know this isn't the best solution, but I tried to install raspbian using the raspberry pi imager, just to see. The SD card is listed, and I can click on the install button. the loading starts and progresses without problems, but when it reaches 99%, the following error is displayed : `write error in storage (error during fsync execution)`

#### CLI-based programs

##### fdisk

When I run `fdisk -l` without sudo permissions, I can see my sd card listed, with the mention `permission not granted`, like the other disks. But when I run it with the sudo permissions, There is no mention of my sd card at all.

### Windows 10 (not really relevant here but maybe it can help you to understand where the problem is)

#### GUI-based programs

##### File Explorer

my SD card isn't listed.

##### Disk Manager

if my SD card is connected, the loading is infinite and the program does not respond.

##### Peripherals and printers/peripherals manager (configuration pannel)

my SD card is listed, but I can't do anything on it. In the peripherals manager, when I go in the properties on my card, then go to 'details' it crashes. when I go to 'Volumes' and try to 'populate', it crashes. In Peripherals and printers, it crashes when I try to display the properties.

##### third-party softwares (like EASEUS partition manager)

my SD card isn't listed

##### Raspberry Pi Imager

My SD card isn't listed, or it's listed for some obscure reason, and when I try to install raspbian, the load remains stuck at `preparing to write (opening drive)`

#### CLI-based programs

##### diskpart, get-volume, ...

if my SD card is connected, the loading is infinite.

##### fsutils, get-psdrive, ...

my Sd card isn't listed.

### Android

I tried to put my sd card on an android smartphone, then go to storage, and then reset it. It aborted and displayed the following toast notification : `command '10 volume partition disk: 179:192 public' failed with '400 10 Command failed'`

## Apparition of the problem

I simply tried to reset my SD card using the dedicated tool in the raspberry pi imager (windows). It kept getting stuck at the first step, something like "preparing to reset", so I clicked cancel after a while, the cancel succeded without any problem. That's all. The SD card didn't have any problem or something.

## Conclusion

As you can see, I tried a lot of different things.  My SD card **is** detected, but I can do nothing on it at all. I really have no idea where the problem is, and how to repair it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Go to `/dev` and see if you have mmblk0 (or 1,2,3..). If found mount that. Also what's `dmesg` output  when you insert it ?

Comment: @IbnFulan well, `mmblik0` *was* displayed, I remember it from the non-sudo execution of `fdisk -l`, but that's not the case anymore. I guess the operations I tried definitively killed it.